# Using seed to sample in tensorflow-probability

Tags: tensorflow, random, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to use `tensorflow-probability` and started off with something really simple:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tf.enable_eager_execution()

tfd = tfp.distributions
poiss = tfd.Poisson(0.8)

poiss.sample(2, seed=1)
#> Out: <tf.Tensor: id=3569, shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)>

poiss.sample(2, seed=1)
#> Out: <tf.Tensor: id=3695, shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 0.], dtype=float32)>

poiss.sample(2, seed=1)
#> Out: <tf.Tensor: id=3824, shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([2., 2.], dtype=float32)>

poiss.sample(2, seed=1)
#> Out: <tf.Tensor: id=3956, shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 1.], dtype=float32)>
```

I was thinking I would get the same results when re-using the same seed, but somehow that's not true.

I also tried without `eager` execution, but the results still weren't reproducible. Same story if I add something like `tf.set_random_seed(12)`.

I suppose there is something basic I am missing?

For those interested, I am running **Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04** with

> tensorflow-probability==0.5.0
>   tensorflow==1.12.0

Answer (score 4):

For deterministic output in graph mode, you need to set both the graph random seed (`tf.set_random_seed`) and the op random seed (`seed=` in your sample call).

The workings of random samplers in TFv2 are still being [sorted out](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/38). For now, my best understanding is that you can call `tf.set_random_seed` prior to *each* call to a sampler, *and* pass the sampler a `seed=`, if you want deterministic output in eager.

Comment: Thanks for the hints and the useful link. So indeed with `eager` I have to call `tf.set_random_seed` prior to *each* call to a sampler (whether I pass the seed to the sampler or not doesn't matter then in terms of reproducibility).

Comment: As for graph mode, if I stay within a session, I would need to keep calling `tf.set_random_seed` similarly. My follow-up question would then be whether there is any side-effect of the specific integers being passed to the ops seed? I.e. does it matter if I pass the same seed to multiple ops? Also happy for a link to a more extensive documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is now cleaner, we support fully deterministic randomness in TFP. You can pass a tuple of two ints for seed, or a Tensor of shape (2,) to trigger the deterministic behavior. tfp.random.split_seed is also relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Besides setting the seed for sample or sample_chain in mcmc, you might need to set the followings as well:

```
seed = 24
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = 'true'
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = f'{seed}'
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```